# Can I get one single correlation value (Pearson Correlation) for 3 variables?

Tags: r, pearson-correlation

I have 3 quantitative variables (Public Ideology, Parties Ideology, Government Ideology) for France,for the year 2017. X, Y, Z.
Can I calculate the Pearson Correlation with Rstudio and get one single value representing how correlated the three variable are?

Comment: The short answer is yes you can get a correlation out of R, but correlations are by design between two variables, so you'd have a total of 3 different correlation scores (X vs Y, X vs Z, Y vs Z).

Answer (score 0):

You could use principal components to identify the maximum covariance of all of the variables. The first component and the amount of variance explained measures their joint   covariance. As an example, here is the iris data set that comes with R. It has four metric measurements, but the process is the same:

```
data(iris)
iris.pca <- prcomp(iris[, 1:4], scale.=TRUE)
summary(iris.pca)
# Importance of components:
#                           PC1    PC2     PC3     PC4
# Standard deviation     1.7084 0.9560 0.38309 0.14393
# Proportion of Variance 0.7296 0.2285 0.03669 0.00518
# Cumulative Proportion  0.7296 0.9581 0.99482 1.00000
```

The first component explains 72.96% of the covariance between the four variables. Using `scale.=TRUE` is important if the variables are measuring different things or at different scales. It converts the variables to Z-scores before the analysis so each variable accounts for 1/k of the total variance where k is the number of variables.

Based on my comments and your code you want something like this:

```
RConvergence <- read.csv("C:/Users/TA/Desktop/RConvergence./RConvergence.csv",sep = ",", header=TRUE)
RConvergence.pca <- prcomp(RConvergence[, 3:5], scale.=TRUE)
summary(RConvergence.pca)
```

To compute this for each country just `split` the data and use `lapply`:

```
RConvergence.split <- split(RConvergence, RConvergence$Country)
RConvergence.split.pca <- lapply(RConvergence.split, function(x) prcomp(x[, 3:5], scale.=TRUE))
lapply(RConvergence.split.pca, summary)
```

Comment: Thank you @dcarlson. I tried your suggestion and also another one but I am getting errors. Please check my answer for further detail and a subset of the data.

Comment: In your code, your data is called `mydata` not `RConvergence`. The `data()` function loads an existing data set, but there is not data set called `RConvergence`. That is the name of your `.csv` file. If you want to use `RConvergence`, change `mydata` to `RConvergence` in line that reads the `.csv` file. You do not need the `data()` command since that is used for R datasets.

Comment: Further down you have `RConvergence.pca <- prcomp(RConvergence.pca[, 1:3], scale.=TRUE)` which fails because you should be analyzing your data `mydata` or `RConvergence` if you have changed it to that. You cannot analyze `RConvergence.pca` because it does not exist yet and it is not a data frame. Finally the numeric columns in your data are 3:5 not 1:3.

Comment: See my revised answer for an application of these suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. it worked. i got an answer but for the complete data set. What I need is the correlation for every state (28 states), for every year (2008-2017). so I need the correlation of Public, Parties, Government for France 2008, France 2009...France 2017; Germany 2008, ....Germany 20017  . Is that possible?

Comment: my input file resemble the following: first column: Country second column: Year (from 2008 to 2017) third column: Public, fourth column: Parties; fifth column :Government

Comment: In the above list, `RConvergence.split.pca` each part is a country, e.g. `RConvergence.split.pca[[1]]` is the result for the first country, etc.

Comment: Is this code also for every year for every country? i

Comment: Try it. This computes the `pca` for each country across the years. If you want each year across the countries change `split(RConvergence, RConvergence$Country)` to `split(RConvergence, RConvergence$Category)`.